# hive not picking up jars from hive.aux.jars.path

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created a hive UDF JAR file and I am trying to deploy it. For this, I have put all the files into my edge node location `/opt/hive/jars` and set this path in `hive-site.xml` file.

```xml
  <property>
    <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
    <value>/opt/hive/jars</value>
  </property>
```

I have restarted by hive server to using following command

```sh
 sudo restart hive-server2
```

However when i login to my `beeline` I am not able to see jars. When I create a function and call it it's giving an error.

**Update 1:**

1. I put the file on hdfs and included that location as well. No luck.
2. I included the same property in `/etc/hive/conf/hiveserver2-site.xml` but no luck.

Directory where Jars are located in owned by hive user and has `777` permission.

**Update 2:**

I checked from which path the other jars files are being picked up.

I put my jars files into these location and restarted the hive server. And Now it's working.

Comment: Did you place your UDF jar on the host running HS2, and give `hive` user permissions to it?

Comment: @mazaneicha hive user has permission. How do I check where HS2, is running? I am able to stop and start hive service from the machine I have put files to.

Comment: You said you are connecting to HS2 via `beeline`. What URL are you using? The <hostname> in that URL is where HS2 is running.

Comment: @mazaneicha than jars are on the right machine